# Como podría generar asignar números random que sean asignados a una imagen para cambiar el orden de piezas en un memorama?

Tags: javascript, html, css, array, game

Antes que nada les pido comprensión recién estoy aprendiendo y se que debo tener no uno, sino varios errores de concepto y de código. Paso a explicarme lo mejor posible estoy intentando realizar un memorama con css, html y javascript con dos botones uno pensado para cargar y otro para refrescar el juego, o sea reiniciarlo. Las diferentes piezas van dispuestas en un grid con efectos de creados en css. Ente otras cosas estoy intentando que las diferentes imágenes de las piezas del juego se reorganicen al pulsar el botón de "Limpiar" la idea que tengo es asignar a cada imagen un numero random y luego reorganizarlas por medio de un array, que creo podria hacerse con un bucle for. Estoy un poco perdido no se si será posible y si la idea que tengo estara bien. Dejo de código que tengo hasta ahora. gracias de antemano.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

<form>
    <fieldset>
        <legend><h1>Modo de juego</h1></legend>
        <p>Oprima el boton "Cargar" o "Limpiar" para empezar un juego nuevo</p>
        <input type="button" name="cargar" value="Cargar" onclick="Cargar()"></input>
        <input type="button" name="limpiar" value="Limpiar" onclick="Limpiar()"></input>
    </fieldset>
</form>



<main class="principal"> <!-- contenido principal dom -->

<div id="all">


<div id="caja1"> <!-- 1 cuadricula del grid -->
<figure class="voltea"> <!-- Imagen 1-1 -->

            <img src="Imagenes/arpa.png" alt="font"> <!-- cara imagen -->

        <div class="estandar"> <!-- Contenedor para igualar tamanio -->

            <img class="back" src="Imagenes/back.png" alt="back"> <!-- back card -->

    </div>
</figure>
</div>



<div id="caja2"> <!-- 2 cuadricula del grid -->
<figure class="voltea"> <!-- Imagen 1-2 -->


            <img src="Imagenes/arpa.png" alt="font"> <!-- cara imagen -->

    <div class="estandar"> <!-- Contenedor para igualar tamanio -->

            <img class="back" src="Imagenes/back.png" alt="back"> <!-- back card -->


    </div>
</figure>
</div>


<div id="caja3"> <!-- 3 cuadricula del grid -->
<figure class="voltea"> <!-- Imagen 2-1 -->


            <img src="Imagenes/violin.png" alt="font"> <!-- cara imagen -->

    <div class="estandar"> <!-- Contenedor para igualar tamanio -->

            <img class="back" src="Imagenes/back.png" alt="back"> <!-- back card -->


    </div>
</figure>
</div>



<div id="caja4"> <!-- 4 cuadricula del grid -->
<figure class="voltea"> <!-- Imagen 2-2 -->


            <img src="Imagenes/violin.png" alt="font"> <!-- cara imagen -->

    <div class="estandar"> <!-- Contenedor para igualar tamanio -->

            <img class="back" src="Imagenes/back.png" alt="back"> <!-- back card -->


    </div>
</figure>
</div>


<div id="caja5"> <!-- 5 cuadricula del grid -->
<figure class="voltea"> <!-- Imagen 3-1 -->


            <img src="Imagenes/piano.png" alt="font"> <!-- cara imagen -->

    <div class="estandar"> <!-- Contenedor para igualar tamanio -->

            <img class="back" src="Imagenes/back.png" alt="back"> <!-- back card -->


    </div>
</figure>
</div>



<div id="caja6"> <!-- 6 cuadricula del grid -->
<figure class="voltea"> <!-- Imagen 3-2 -->


            <img src="Imagenes/piano.png" alt="font"> <!-- cara imagen -->

    <div class="estandar"> <!-- Contenedor para igualar tamanio -->

            <img class="back" src="Imagenes/back.png" alt="back"> <!-- back card -->


    </div>
</figure>
</div>



<div id="caja7"> <!-- 7 cuadricula del grid -->
<figure class="voltea"> <!-- Imagen 4-1 -->


            <img src="Imagenes/saxo.png" alt="font"> <!-- cara imagen -->

    <div class="estandar"> <!-- Contenedor para igualar tamanio -->

            <img class="back" src="Imagenes/back.png" alt="back"> <!-- back card -->


    </div>
</figure>
</div>



<div id="caja8"> <!-- 8 cuadricula del grid -->
<figure class="voltea"> <!-- Imagen 4-2 -->


            <img src="Imagenes/saxo.png" alt="font"> <!-- cara imagen -->

    <div class="estandar"> <!-- Contenedor para igualar tamanio -->

            <img class="back" src="Imagenes/back.png" alt="back"> <!-- back card -->


    </div>
</figure>
</div>



<div id="caja9"> <!-- 9 cuadricula del grid -->
<figure class="voltea"> <!-- Imagen 5-1 -->


            <img src="Imagenes/guitarra.png" alt="font"> <!-- cara imagen -->

    <div class="estandar"> <!-- Contenedor para igualar tamanio -->

            <img class="back" src="Imagenes/back.png" alt="back"> <!-- back card -->


    </div>
</figure>
</div>



<div id="caja10"> <!-- 10 cuadricula del grid -->
<figure class="voltea"> <!-- Imagen 5-2 -->


            <img src="Imagenes/guitarra.png" alt="font"> <!-- cara imagen -->

    <div class="estandar"> <!-- Contenedor para igualar tamanio -->

            <img class="back" src="Imagenes/back.png" alt="back"> <!-- back card -->


    </div>
</figure>
</div>



<div id="caja11"> <!-- 11 cuadricula del grid -->
<figure class="voltea"> <!-- Imagen 6-1 -->

            <img src="Imagenes/trompeta.png" alt="font"> <!-- cara imagen -->

    <div class="estandar"> <!-- Contenedor para igualar tamanio -->

            <img class="back" src="Imagenes/back.png" alt="back"> <!-- back card -->


    </div>
</figure>
</div>



<div id="caja12"> <!-- 12 cuadricula del grid -->
<figure class="voltea"> <!-- Imagen 6-2 -->


            <img src="Imagenes/trompeta.png" alt="font"> <!-- cara imagen (imagen random) -->

    <div class="estandar"> <!-- Contenedor para igualar tamanio -->

            <img class="back" src="Imagenes/back.png" alt="back"> <!-- cara imagen -->


    </div>
</figure>
</div>




</div>

</main> 


<script type="text/javascript">


function Cargar() {

    document.getElementById('all').style.display = 'flex';

}

for (var i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
    

    math.random()


}


function Limpiar() {


}

</script>


<style type="text/css">

.all {

    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr); /*grid template 4 columnas - unidad fraccion css fraccion espacio restante, fr representa una fraccion de espacio restante del contenedor - repeat repite 4 veces las columnas que se achican o agrandan, dependiendo el espacio disponible */
    max-width: auto;
    margin: auto;
    grid-gap: 2px;

}

#all {

    display: none;
}

figure {

    position: relative;
    transform-style: preserve-3d; /*preserva el estilo 3d de padres a hijos de figure en el espacio*/
    transform: perspective(600px) rotateY(0deg); /*Rota la back card*/
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px


}

figure img {

    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}

.estandar {

    position: absolute; { /*La posicion absolute modifica el flujo por lo que la imagen puede sobreponerse*/
    top: 0px;               /* Los 0 pixeles logran una superposicion complata del div estandar que contiene la imagen font*/
    transform: perspective(600px) rotateY(180deg); /* Rota la cara visible de la carta  
    pespective: crea una matriz de transformacion de objetos individuales para dar perspectiva de cizallamiento, rotacion, escala, etc
    rotate: define la transformacion de un objeto que gira sobre un punto fijo sin deformarlo; /*
}

.voltea { /*busca la figure que tenga la clase "voltea"*/

transform: perspective(600px) rotateY(180deg); /* Deg = expresado en grados sexagesimales*/

}



</style>
    

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te explico como lo haría yo. Empezaría borrando todo el contenido que está dentro de la etiqueta `<div id="all">`, para insertarlo desde JavaScript.

Obtienes el div para luego insertar los datos

```
const gameBox = document.getElementById('all');
```

Añades los nombres de las "cartas" en un array

```
var cartas = ["arpa","arpa","violin","violin","piano","piano","saxo","saxo"]
```

Ahora hacemos una función para desordenar el array

```
function desordenar(c){
    return c.sort(function() { return Math.random() - 0.5 });
}
```

Y por último la función que imprimirá el memorama

```
function imprimir(c){
    let template = '';

    for(let i = 0; i < c.length; i++){
        template += `
            <div id="caja${i+1}"> 
                <figure class="voltea">   
                    <img src="Imagenes/${c[i]}.png" alt="font">  ${c[i]}
                        <div class="estandar">      
                            <img class="back" src="Imagenes/back.png" alt="back"> 
                        </div>
                </figure>
            </div>
        `;
    }
    gameBox.innerHTML = template;
}
```

Si quieres que lo imprima ordenado tienes que poner lo siguiente

```
imprimir(cartas);
```

Y si quieres que lo imprima desordenado lo tienes que poner así

```
imprimir(desordenar(cartas));
```